# How to send push notification from a React Native Amplify App?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

We have an app same as FB, where a user can send request to other user and accept the request. So we wanted to send a notification when a user send a connection request or someones request accept. We want to send push notifications from both iOS and Android app.

Can anyone help me how we can implement this?

I have checked the Amplify Docs but they only mentioned the stuff related to receiving push notifications, not how to send them.

Can anyone help me how we can implement this?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/getting-started-with-push-notifications-using-aws-amplify/.

Comment: @user18309290 thanks for providing the link. But first, how we can send notifications for both iOS and Android devices, and second, do we need to create a Lambda function to send notifications and call it using GraphQL?